# Why length_batch calling my single row function in ESPER CEP query multiple times?

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

I am using the ESPER CEP engine for processing real-time streams of weather data. I have a use-case where I am doing a batch of the streams using length_batch i.e. AvgWeatherEvent.win:length_batch(5) and calling my single row function for taking an average.

My ESPER queries:

```
// Create my Event
String createEventExpAvg = "@EventRepresentation(objectarray) create schema AvgWeatherEvent as (prop1 Map)";

// My Select query with single row function
String expr = "select transpose(compute_avg(f)) from AvgWeatherEvent.win:length_batch(5) as f"
```

Where compute_avg is my single row function calculating an average.

The problem is the query is calling my single row function 5 times (which is the batch size I mentioned in length_batch). Is this expected behavior? Due to this, I am getting multiple duplicated rows in my output. As per my understanding, it should call the function only once when the batch_size becomes 5.

Is there any way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
select transpose(compute_avg(window(*))) from AvgWeatherEvent#length_batch(5)
```

Comment: If you have "compute_avg(f)" and since "compute_avg" is a single row function and not an aggregation function each "f" is an event.